# Can I force a link to open in a browser instead of webview?

Tags: android, webview

We are pushing ads on Youtube and Facebook of our service.

We have noticed that, when users comes Facebook, after clicking on the link of our website, Facebook opens a webview to display our website, instead of launching chrome or firefox.

We wanted the link to open the browser instead of a webview because, when the browser is opened, users using Chrome are logged in and it is easy for them to use our service based on Google login systems.

When it is the webview, it is like if their are in incognit mode. They have to login first to Google, before accessing our service...

As conquence, we loose 90% of our users.

When users comes from Youtube for example, Youtube opens directly chrome, users are already logged in and access our services faster.

Please how could we force a link to open our site in a browser instead of webview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability of an application to open links in an external view depends on whether the application has overridden `WebViewClient`. [As the source code comment says](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClient.java):

"Give the host application a chance to take control when a URL is about to be loaded in the current `WebView`. If a `WebViewClient` is not provided, by default `WebView` will ask `Activity Manager` to choose the proper handler for the URL".

Thus, if the default `WebViewClient` is overridden in the application, and the display is configured in the embedded `WebView`, then you will not be able to achieve the behavior of opening a link in an external view when clicking on a link